# Is it possible to change the margins for just footnotes (not the entire document)?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2007 and there have been times when I would like to slightly tweak the margins for some of the footnotes.  Adjusting margins for individual footnotes seems like asking too much, but is there an easy way to adjust the footnote margins in general, using Word 2007?

Comment: I don't have Word 2007 to try this on so I'll make it a comment instead of an answer, but in Word for Mac, the header, footer, and document itself all have separate rulers so you can adjust the margin of all of them independently. If I save that as a Word 97-2004 Document, the differing margins are preserved, so it seems that's supported at least back to Word 97. On the Mac I get to it using View > Header and Footer, and with View > Rulers checked, you can click in the area you want to change the margins of and drag the margins in the ruler.

Comment: blm: Thank you for your reply.  I inadvertently discovered the same thing once I had turned my ruler on.  For some reason, I had it turned off, and consequently, it seemed a bit of a mystery to me.  I guess the lesson here is: Never underestimate the value of a measuring stick!  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footnotes have the style "Footnote Text" applied to them.  This is a paragraph style so you can modify its Left and Right Indentation to "mimic" have different margins for the footnote section.

(You might also want to change the position of the Footnote Separator and Footnote Continuation Separator so it's aligned with your new footnote text indent - via View, Normal then Show Footnotes and you can select the separators from the dropdown menu and edit).

Comment: Although blm's answer was good, I don't know that I would have ever thought to analyze the style applied to the text.  You'll make a super**user** out of me yet, @Tanya, and for that, you get the coveted green checkmark.